# Redundant Skill Selection in 4th edition Dungeons and Dragons

Tags: dnd-4e, skills

Good evening:

I was looking over some of the classes in the Player's Handbook and found something I must not have noticed when I had first started playing: redundant skill selection for some classes, most notably for those with either arcane or divine power sources. For example, the cleric seems to innately get Religion as a skill, but may also choose Religion from the other skills.

Thus, is that secondary skill (religion) even necessary to be noted as one of the skills able to be selected by a cleric? If I were to take that skill from the class skills, would be it supplemental to the innate bonus? To emphasize this in an example form, would it then be possible to make a cleric that is /not/ trained in religion (every cleric that I have encountered by other players and made by myself has been trained in religion, though).

I do not have my books with me as I type this now, but it is something that came up to me to mull over these past few months.

Thank you in advanced for any help you may provide--please, tell me if and where it is clearly stated in the rules and errata wherein this seeming redundancy is noted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an accident of efficiencies used in arranging the text.

The (e.g.) Cleric says that they get Religion as a trained skill immediately. And then it says you can select more from the list below. The list below is not a single-purpose list that exists only for this choosing step though, it's doing double-duty placed there. What that list actually is primarily, is a complete list of all **class skills** for a Cleric, which would be incomplete if it lacked Religion. Necessarily, you choose your three other trained skills from the Cleric's class skills.

The way it's phrased makes it appear redundant, but if you were coming to that page to find the list of class skills for some other purpose, it would be alarming to *not* find Religion listed as a class skill.

Comment: The Class Skill list is also extremely relevant to Multiclass feats (PHB1), and might be relevant to Hybrid classes (I can't check at the moment if this is true). If Religion weren't listed in the Class Skills, a Multiclass Cleric would be unable to get Religion for a skill!

Comment: Indeed, Hybrids are not automatically trained in skills their parent classes are automatically trained in.